# How to instantiate a Stackpanel that includes other elements?

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to make a dynamically make a row of multiple things, like a FaceBook feed with multiple entries, it includes the profile picture, name, text and comment section and such.

I have a Stackpanel with the name `HomeFeedStackPanel`. I want to put a grid, with some content in there inside of that StackPanel. I put the grid + it's element into `<Window.Resources>`. and it's Key is `FeedPostEntry` and it's Name is `fpe`.

```
<Window.Resources>

        ...

        <!-- Static Resource -->
        <Grid x:Key="FeedPostEntry" Name="fpe" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FF2E2E2E" Grid.RowSpan="2" RadiusY="7" RadiusX="7"/>
            <Image x:Name="userPic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Width="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2"/>
            <Label x:Name="Username" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SimSun" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window.Resources>
```

How do I add that Grid, including it's elements, into the StackPanel via C#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't place your `Grid` in the `Resources`, but rather define it in the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemTemplate` like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="HomeFeedStackPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <Grid x:Key="FeedPostEntry" Name="fpe" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF2E2E2E" Grid.RowSpan="2" RadiusY="7" RadiusX="7"/>
        <Image x:Name="userPic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Width="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="Username" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SimSun" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the content holding controls (like `Label` or `Image`) you should then define the bindings to your data.

Comment: Ah, Thank you. And how do I then instantiate it via code?

Comment: Why do you want to do this from code behind? Use XAML instead.

Comment: I want to have it dynamic. I am going to get entries from a social website, and I need to have multiple of those depending on how many posts there are. Something that shows the avatar, username and stuff. I can't do that with XAML, or can I?

Comment: Please read about [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Comment: I don't know how it works, care to explain the critical parts please?